# iPhone 6 keyboard help lost emoji's

Tags: keyboard, iphone, emoji

I installed a new keyboard then deleted it now I've lost all my emoji off my standered keyboard just got a-z 0-9 #+=

Someone help please?

Comment: Have you gone to settings/general/keyboard/keyboards and used the edit button to delete the Emoji keyboard and then used Add Keyboard to add it again?

Comment: Only thing I can add is English uk qwerty nothing else :(

Comment: You should be able to add a couple dozen keyboards. Try resetting your device

Answer (score 2):

You can go to Settings > General > Keyboards > Add New Keyboard ... and select "Emoji" from the list. Then, in order to access the emojis on your keyboard, tab this "globe" icon:

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is called a "Globe icon." It looks like a globe. In iOS <8, Emoji's weren't standard; they had to be enabled through "Settings -> General -> Keyboards -> Emoji". Since "Emoji" was a type of different keyboard language, it was pretty much another locale, and that was the reasoning behind that original globe icon. In the development for iOS 8, since most of these Emojis are smileys, they replaced the button with a smiley-face.

Comment: Nice, thanks... with a lot of imagination, I can see the "globe" now ;)

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 6 iOS 10.2 - Emoji keyboard wouldn't load until I deleted a load of foreign keyboards I didn't require. Had 40 loaded so perhaps too many to cope. That sorted it for me :)